# Any website has live report events of a football match?

Tags: football

I am looking for a website which tell you events of a football match when a match is running in details like: freeshot, change player, player injured, shoot, goal ... events ! Does anything like that exist ?

Comment: I don't think this is really constructive as its mostly a shopping question.

Comment: check flashscore.com. For almost every match it provides live scoring, changes, injuries, handballs, offsides etc.

Answer (score 6):

[`www.sportinglife.com`](http://www.sportinglife.com/) specializes in English Premier League games.  If you use the [`Football`](http://www.sportinglife.com/football/news/) link on the left nav pane, and then choose the [`Live`](http://www.sportinglife.com/football/live/latestscores/) menu item, you will see all the games they monitor for the day.  Within the listed matches, you will always find (relatively) up to date scores and scorers.  For the games that have links, you will find play-by-play updates.

Comment: The website is good but it seem to only show the important events, no change player, player injured, free kick, corner kick, shoot, ect,... events.

Answer (score 3):

I think [livesoccertv](http://www.livesoccertv.com/) will fit your needs. This site ultimately covers all the requirements of football lovers.Furthermore, you can view the [livescore](http://www.livesoccertv.com/live-scores/) and much more.

Comment: The website is good but it seem to only show the important events, no change player, player injured, free kick, corner kick, shoot, ect,... events.